# Mac Terminal Directory

Tags: macos, terminal

I realize my directory at the top is spelled wrongly and now I can't do any cmd on my terminal. How do I go about to change it back or undo it?

screenshot

[image: 1]

The path is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to edit your `~/.bash_profile` and fix what is wrong there.

This file might be invisible, so when you open Finder, press `CMD`+`Shift`+`.` to make these files appear. You can press that combination again to hide them, after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In their terminal app go to Terminal > Preferences. Under "Shells open with," select "Command (complete path)," then enter the path `/usr/bin/bash`.